# What is the best Open Source Alternative to Datadog

Tags: monitoring, system-monitor

I'm researching what is the best opensource method to replace our companies Datadog Implementation

**Implementation**

*Datadog Agents*

- Running on Ubuntu and Android Devices, essentially statsd wrappers, that send specific data

  - Host Responding
  - Cpu
  - Ip
  - Memory

*Visualize the Data*

- Datadog provides built in visualization dashboards

*Create Monitors*

- Based on the status of the device

*API Access*

- An API for external services